# How to build and run an Erlang project in Cygwin/Unix/CentOS?

Tags: windows-10, unix, centos-7

I am learning Erlang and now i am trying to run some sample projects from git. But i could not build or run them. I would like to know how to do these and the background process involved while building and running the projects.Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried and where did you get stuck?

Comment: I cloned sample random erlang project from git. Next tried to run it from eclipse(I added the necessary plugins) but couldn't and i also tried to build by cygwin and through centOS but no luck. Is there a way to know the starting module and the first method that would be called (or) Is there a way to directly run the project after build i.e. is there any command for that?

Comment: Note that I'm not an Erlang programmer and you may be able to get better help on [SO], **but** before you move your question there (flag it and ask a mod to do so), you should [edit] your question and show 1) which sample project you downloaded, 2) what you did in Eclipse and whether you got any errors (“you couldn't” is a little vague) and 3) which commands you ran in Cygwin. Right now it's hard to help you since your question is rather vague.